# .htaccess is correct but not working in my Laravel project in windows

Tags: php, html, laravel, windows, .htaccess

I am using Laravel 8x and Xampp in my window.
I have created the project and put it into htdocs and there is a correct .htaccess file but not working correctly.

Comment: Personal recommendation, **urgently** change to `Docker`, as `xampp` is old and you will never use it in a professional place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please find apache2.conf and change Aside Null => All